# How can I run a check on page-load (server-side) on a website which includes both aspx pages and mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pageload

I want to run a version consistency check between the website and database on every page in the software I work on to see whether one or the other is out of sync. (background: someone could upgrade while a user is using the software, so restricting the check to the sign in page isn't realistic - also why the check is required on any page in the software).

I am not in control of the deployment, as the customer hosts the software themselves on their own hardware.

The front-end is a mixture of asp.net pages and MVC4 (gradually replacing the aspx pages with MVC) , so I can't simply just run the check on `Page_Load()` in our inner and outer basepages and then have something different for our MVC pages - I would rather not duplicate code for each page type.

Having a look around, I have seen filters which exist for MVC which could be an option for those pages.

I've been investigating HttpHandlers and in theory could restrict the requests down to page load and not static content.

Is there an alternative/better way to do this server side check which would have the code in just one place and would affect both aspx pages and MVC?

Comment: I think you've got an XY Problem here. Rather than adding some check everywhere, you might want to consider different rollout practices. For example, only update the website during scheduled maintenance. Or use staged rollouts where you set up a another database and web server and deploy to that, and once deployment is complete taking the existing servers offline and switch to the new ones.

Comment: What does the Check do on Pass/Fail?

Comment: Application Begin Request is a placeholder where you could run something to check the same. Instead I would add a piece of JS in the browser so the check is not in the normal request pipeline. The JS code will ping the server with request URL. I am assuming you just want to make sure at the time of active request if the server is in process of an update you want to notify the user of inconsistent behaviour

Comment: @mason - I'm not in control of the rollout - the software is hosted by our customers on their own hardware.

Comment: @bUKaneer - It's basically just seeing if the website and database are different versions from each other and warning them if they are. Ideally they shouldn't see the page at all but it's a failsafe just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what it should do when its passes the check or fails the check you could set up a new controller `Version` with an action `Check`

```
public class Version : Controller
{
  public JsonResult Check() {
    return new Json((GetWebsiteVersionNumber() == GetDatabaseVersionNumber()));
  }
}
```

You can then call this endpoint from MVC using @Html.Action in _Layout or in another view and respond accordingly. On the Web Forms side you can then call this end point using the serverside WebRequest class and take appropriate action depending upon the response from your MasterPage PageLoad event or anywhere else you prefer.

Further you could call the endpoint from a common javascript file i(ncluded on both the WebForms and MVC client side includes) and using an AJAX request get the response and deal with it there also.

Excuse syntax errors as I was writing this off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks, we ideally wanted it server-side but we've now restricted it to certain pages instead.